# How can I center the image?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I want to horizontally center an image in my paper by the code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn,oneside,a4paper]{article}
...
...
...
\begin{figure*}[]
HK1706 (in 2017)
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 1.15\textwidth]{materials/aaa.jpg}
\caption{Map of the study area showing sampling stations and station numbers. }
\label{Figure 3}
\end{figure*}
```

But the image in pdf exported is off to the right like the attached image. It seems to be left-justified.
How can I fix this and center the image?

[image: A part of exported pdf]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In fact, `\textwidth` is the width of the paper margin (the part to print the text, if I use a wrong word), so `1.15\textwidth` is wider than the margin, or, your picture requires more space than expected. Therefore it can't be centered by `\centering`. I recommend using `x\textwidth` for `0 < x <= 1`. Otherwise, you must need some more strategy.

Comment: Welcome! It would make our lives simpler if you could make your minimal working example (MWE) self-contained. By this I mean that it include `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` and all necessary packages (just `graphicx` in this case) so that we don't have to add these ourselves when we want to run/modify your code.

Comment: Centering will work if you use wrap your image in a box of width `\linewidth`, with `\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[…]{…}}` btw. (See e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207087/156366).)

Comment: Why don't you replace `\includegraphics[width = 1.15\textwidth]{materials/aaa.jpg}` with `\includegraphics[width = 1.0\textwidth]{materials/aaa.jpg}`? Put differently, what are you trying to achieve by making the image wider than the textblock?

Comment: \usepackage[export]{adjustbox} and then `\includegraphics[width = 1.15\textwidth,center]{materials/aaa.jpg}`. Please see [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16582/2975).

Comment: @JouleV   Thank you for a comment and welcoming! I understood about the point of this error. I will try the code in answer.

Comment: @Circumscribe   Thank you for welcoming! Oh you are right. I will make sure to make my code examples possible to run as they are.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for a comment! I wanted to put my image big as possible, even bigger than textwidth. Maybe I should have edited  my image to make it looks good in textwidth.

Comment: @MartinScharre   Thank you for a comment! I will see that page and try the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just fool LaTeX with a `\makebox[\linewidth]`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[]

HK1706 (in 2017)
\centering
\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width = 1.15\textwidth]{materials/aaa.jpg}}
\caption{Map of the study area showing sampling stations and station numbers. }
\label{Figure 3}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This code works! Thank you for this answer.